# Convert xsd to xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

How can I generate xml from xsd **without xsd.exe**?

Comment: what should be in xml , just dummy data ?

Comment: have you googled for solition?

Comment: because xml must generate automaticly

Answer (score 12):

I think I googled it for you. Use `XmlSampleGenerator` from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx)

Sample use:

```
XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("po.xml", null);
textWriter.Formatting    = Formatting.Indented;
XmlQualifiedName qname   = new XmlQualifiedName("PurchaseOrder",       
                           "http://tempuri.org");
XmlSampleGenerator generator = new XmlSampleGenerator("po.xsd", qname);
genr.WriteXml(textWriter);
```

Comment: Sorry, but do you have other ideas? I cannot use XMLSampleGenerator.

Comment: Did you even look? XmlSamplegenerator != xsd.exe, for starters. Note that the word MSDN is a hyperlink to ... the [source code for XmlSamplegenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for this example, just what I needed. I don't want to store the xsd or xml on disk.

Comment: Ah. That snarky tone... "I googled it for" me too: [tweet](https://twitter.com/sehetw/status/361789757791014912)

Comment: I am getting error - The type or namespace name 'Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'. Even after downloading it from Nuget

Answer (score 3):

The problem has solved.

```
private void CreateXML(XmlNode xsdNode, XmlElement element, ref XmlDocument xml)
    {
        if (xsdNode.HasChildNodes)
        {
            var childs = xsdNode.ChildNodes;
            foreach (XmlNode node in childs)
            {
                XmlElement newElement = null;
                if (node.Name == "xs:element")
                {
                    newElement = xml.CreateElement(node.Attributes["name"].Value);
                    CreateXML(node, newElement, ref xml);
                    if (element == null)
                        xml.AppendChild(newElement);
                    else
                        element.AppendChild(newElement);
                }
                if (node.Name == "xs:attribute")
                {
                    element.SetAttribute(node.Attributes["name"].Value, "");
                }
                if ((node.Name == "xs:complexType") || (node.Name == "xs:sequence") || (node.Name == "xs:schema"))
                    CreateXML(node, element, ref xml);
            }
        }
    }
```

How-to use

```
XmlDocument xsd = new XmlDocument();
xsd.Load(xsdFileName);
XmlNode xsdNode = xsd.DocumentElement;
XmlElement element = null;
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
CreateXML(xsdNode, element, ref xml);
```